# Read a property from a DBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to get an JSON array into a var in java. My JSON seems ok but when i try to put a JSOn array into a java array var it does not work.
here the error i get : errororg.json.JSONException: JSONObject["tweets"] is not a JSONArray.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test1" );


    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("tweetsCol");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {

        BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        JSONObject objjj = new JSONObject(obj);
        try{
            System.out.println("okok "+objjj); // THE JSON I WILL SHOW YOU

            JSONArray jsonMainArr = objjj.getJSONArray("tweets");

        }catch(JSONException e){
            System.out.println("error"+e);
        }}
```

Here's my data in MongoDB:

```
{
   "_id":"5939bc6676abbe186feb73a5",
   "user_request_id":"5941903f37aaa6ec55689e85",
   "tweets":[
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 07 18:32:57 CDT 2017",
         "text":"[Earthview Wonders][Video] No.265: Astronaut Thomas Pesquet completed 6-month #MissionProxima. #Neweyes\u2026 ",
         "_id":872597276891398144,
         "user":"livearthjp"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 07 18:16:56 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Astronaut Thomas Pesquet @Thom_astro Shares His #Songs4Space ",
         "_id":872593245716467712,
         "user":"anasia5mice"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 07 15:46:03 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Thomas Pesquet: Undocking and landing ",
         "_id":872555275387117570,
         "user":"GRASSIFREE"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 17:02:37 CDT 2017",
         "text":"@Thom_astro @Space_Station And his colleagues said, 'Pesquet, if you play Baker Street one more time...'",
         "_id":877647972430823429,
         "user":"kimkemmis"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 17:01:16 CDT 2017",
         "text":"[News] ",
         "_id":877647632524394497,
         "user":"ArthurC2Pouce"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 11:28:48 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Thomas Pesquet's music is OUT THERE! Cool dude. ",
         "_id":877563967178104836,
         "user":"tiarudd34"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 11:10:15 CDT 2017",
         "text":"jaime thomas pesquet",
         "_id":877559296741048320,
         "user":"sosthene_maus"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 10:23:03 CDT 2017",
         "text":"French astronaut Thomas Pesquet took some of the most amazing pictures ever while in spce ",
         "_id":877547418606329861,
         "user":"raygibbs1"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 10:23:00 CDT 2017",
         "text":"French astronaut Thomas Pesquet shares stunning pictures of Earth: via @AOL",
         "_id":877547405180157952,
         "user":"raygibbs1"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 08:46:13 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Coll Cambuston like Thomas Pesquet! @thomastro @cardierun",
         "_id":877523048546676736,
         "user":"CambF974"
      },
      {
         "date":"Wed Jun 21 08:00:06 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Thomas Pesquet returned to Earth on 2 June 2017 after completion of his six-months long Proxima mission to the... ",
         "_id":877511443775619072,
         "user":"rospaceagency"
      },
      {
         "date":"Tue Jun 20 23:50:34 CDT 2017",
         "text":"Thomas Pesquet @Thom_astro and Messier 83 #Astronauts #ESA @CNES #NASA ✨\u200d✨ ",
         "_id":877388248368033794,
         "user":"AmirAliBehrooz"
      }
   ],
   "query_name":"Pesquet",
   "active":"true",
   "started_at":"2017_06_08"
}
```

Comment: It's not JSON. It's a [`BasicDBObject`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) just like your code actually defines. Instead you access properties using the available methods, and not from a JSONObject`. They are two different things.

Comment: Simply `obj.get("tweets")`. No need for JSON conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand better your question thanks to @Neil Lunn, and following his best advice, you have to understand that you are not dealing here with Json, you can directly do:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "test1" );


    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("tweetsCol");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find();

    while (cursor.hasNext()) {

        BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
        try{
            System.out.println("okok "+obj); // THE JSON I WILL SHOW YOU

            BasicDBList jsonMainArr = obj.get("tweets");

        }catch(JSONException e){
            System.out.println("error"+e);
        }}
```

Comment: It's not JSON. The OP is mistaken and doing it wrong. There is already an accessor as `BasicDBObject` is an abstract `Map`

Comment: @NeilLunn aah.. I see, thanks for clearing up

Comment: Question was misleading due to the misconception. Thanks for pretty printing the data in it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Sure no problem, I was trying to understand the problem behind, I will update the answer refering you, if you dnt mind